# Buscar con la snackbar

Tags: android, listview

Sería posible buscar items del *ListView* con el botón **FAB** y la Snackbar, no tengo ni idea de como hacerlo.

Al pulsar el boton **FAB**, me abre la `SnackBar`, pues en ese momento, que me salga el teclado y mientras voy pulsando caracteres, vaya eliminando de la lista los ítems que no contienen esas letras que yo pulso.

Código:

```
public class FragGridCampos extends Fragment {

    //Creating a List of jornadas
    private List<Estadisticas> listJornadas;

    //Creating Views
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.campos_list, null);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById( R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(
            getActivity(), 1
        );
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        TextView miTexto = (TextView)view.findViewById( R.id.mi_texto);
        miTexto.setText("CAMPOS");
        //miTexto.setTextColor(color.RED);

        listJornadas = new ArrayList<>();

        getData();

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DecoracionLineaDivisoria(getActivity()));

        ImageButton fabButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(
                //  getActivity(),"Probando si funciona",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                //).show();

                final Snackbar snackBar = Snackbar.make(
                    view.findViewById(R.id.fab),
                    "A ver si consigo buscar",
                    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG
                );
                snackBar.setAction("Buscar", new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(
                        //  getActivity(),
                        //  "Probando si funciona tambien",
                        //  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        //).show();
                       snackBar.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                snackBar.setActionTextColor(Color.CYAN);
                View sbView = snackBar.getView();
                TextView textView = (TextView) sbView.findViewById(
                    android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text
                );
                textView.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
                snackBar.show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    //This method will get data from the web api
    private void getData(){
        //Showing a progress dialog
        final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(
            getActivity(), "Cargando datos", "Por favor espere...", false, false
        );
        //Creating a json array request
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest( ConfigAmaters.CAMPOS,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    //Dismissing progress dialog
                    loading.dismiss();

                    //calling method to parse json array
                    parseData(response);
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }
        );
        //Creating request queue
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());

        //Adding request to the queue
        requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
    }
    //This method will parse json data
    private void parseData(JSONArray array){

        for(int i = 0; i<array.length(); i++) {
            Estadisticas comida = new Estadisticas();
            JSONObject json = null;
            try {
                json = array.getJSONObject(i);

                comida.setNombre_campo(json.getString("nombre_campo"));
                comida.setPoblacion(json.getString("poblacion"));
                comida.setEquipo(json.getString("equipo"));
                comida.setTelefono(json.getString("telefono"));
                comida.setGeo(json.getString("geo"));
                comida.setUrl(json.getString("url"));
                comida.setEmail(json.getString("email"));

                comida.setEscudo(json.getString("escudo"));

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            listJornadas.add(comida);
        }
        //Finally initializing our adapter
        adapter = new Campos_Adapter(listJornadas, getActivity());

        //Adding adapter to recyclerview
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: no entiendo bien lo que quieres hacer.

Comment: Al pulsar el boton FAB, me abre la SnackBar, pues en ese mometo que me salga el teclado y mientras voy pulsando caracteres, vaya eliminando de la lista los items que no contienen esas letras que yo pulso.

Comment: vas a necesitar poner un searchview adentro del snackbar para hacer lo que queres, declarar el searchview y programarlo para que busque loq ue queres